# Huge led matrix - using mm5451

Tags: schematics, matrix

Hi I'm using the MM5451 led driver chip to source current for my led matrix. Am told that the chip has open drain outputs. To source current from the chip do I just connect the anode of my led to the output then connect the cathode to my circuit gnd? Also am unsure how it limits the current going to each led? The datasheet says 40ma is the absolute max for each output.

http://www.micrel.com/_PDF/mm5450.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue here is the "open drain".

Basically each output is a switch which is connected to ground.  This switch goes between the cathode of your LED and ground, and you feed your power supply into the anode of each LED.

If you look on page 8 of the data sheet you see an example with lots of 7 segment LED displays.  You can see the "Vled" is connected to all the displays through a pair of transistors - these are just used to switch between left and right halves of the display to get twice as many digits - and there is no ground connection from the displays.  This is because each cathode goes into the chip and then to ground.

The chip itself doesn't source any current, it just sinks it.

As for the current limiting, yes, it is very vague.  Looking at the data table you can see that when a segment is off then the output voltage is at 3V.

This is the same voltage you should be providing to the anode of your LEDs.

When the segment is turned on the output voltage "drops" to 1.8V.  This means that when the output is "on" it has a voltage drop of 1.8V to ground.  With a 3V supply to your LED anode this would equate to 3V - 1.8V = 1.2V for running the LED.

This is the same as having a resistor that drops 1.8v at the current your LED draws.

Comment: ok but the problem is the leds are bi colour common cathode and parallel only hence i have to use the anode to drive he led to switch between colours. that why i wanted to source instead of sink. sorry i wasn clear on that. Does this mean this chip is unsitable then? I did reasearch what open drain meant. The way it was phrased led me to believe it was suitable

Comment: You could use common cathode leds in a way similar to the multiplexing as shown in the datasheet, but then you must do multiplexing in the software that drives the MM chip, which negates most of its usefullness.

Comment: The ds says it's a non multiplexing chip anyways. Instead of using transistors, I'll use a 7HC595 to do the multiplexing of the anodes.

Answer (score 2):

The chip outputs act as constant current sinks. You set the current by seleting the resistor on pin 19. No need to include series resistors for each LED.

These chip are made for common-anode use. Connect all anodes to the + power, cathodes each to an output pin of the chip.